# Scilab - How to get the maximum absolute value in a Matrix with its original sign?

Tags: matlab, max, scilab, absolute-value

I am using Scilab 5.5.2

I am trying to get the maximum absolute value in a vector.

See this example

```
a = [-9;-19;11]
```

If I type:

```
max(abs(a))
```

I get:

```
19
```

That's close to what I want. Yes, 19 is the maximum absolute value. However, **I would like to have the maximum absolute value in its original form, in this case, as -19.**

How can I solve this? Is there a command in Scilab especially designed for that?

I tried looking at documentation but couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find *where* the maximum happens and then get the value there:

```
[word, idx]=max(abs(a));
maximum=a(idx);
```

Comment: Could you help me to adapt this for Scilab?

Comment: @Harry I have not scliab in my PC, but reading the docs, this should work I think. Perhaps you need `[m, idx]=max(abs(a));`

Comment: [It's the same thing](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/max.html)